# printing outputs of different types of arrays of an union

Tags: c, linux, unions

I created an union and I put different types of array inside of it. I printed outputs in an order and I really didn't understand some points.

1) Why is my char array's length always 8 even the content is different? There is only "hello" inside of it. And why does the output is "Cats rock!" when I try to print for second time. I didn't put anything like that inside array.

2)Again length problem. Lenghts of all my arrays are 8 even the length of union. Why?

3) My last question is why double number's value changed when I try to print for the second time.

I'm posting you my code and out put that I get. Sorry about long post, but I'm really confused.

```
char: hello, 8
double: 5.557111111111111, 8
int: 1937006915 1668248096 8555, 8

char: Cats rock!
double: 0.000000000000000
int: 1937006915 1668248096 8555
size of union: 8
```

my code

```
#define NUM1 5.557111111111111

#define NUM2 1937006915
#define NUM3 1668248096
#define NUM4 8555
#include <stdio.h>

/*created an union*/
typedef union {
    char  * array1;
    double num;
    int * array2;
} myunion;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    /* declaring union variable */
    myunion uni;
    /* creating my string */
    char strarray[] = "hello";

    /* declare an int array*/
    int numarray[] = { NUM2, NUM3, NUM4 };

    /* assign the string to the char pointer in the union */
    uni.array1 = strarray;

    /*  print the union and the sizeof of the pointer */
    printf("char: %s, %zu\n", uni.array1,sizeof(uni.array1));

    /* assign NUM1 to the double part of union */
    uni.num = NUM1;

    /* print the double and its sizeof */
    printf("double: %10.15f, %zu\n", uni.num, sizeof(uni.num));

    /* assign array2 of union  to the numarray */
    uni.array2 = numarray;

    /* print the values and the sizeof */
    printf("int: %d %d %d, %zu\n", uni.array2[0], uni.array2[1], uni.array2[2], sizeof(uni.array2));

    /* print the char array, double and int array */
    printf("\nchar: %s \ndouble: %10.15f \nint: %d %d %d\n",uni.array1, uni.num, uni.array2[0], uni.array2[1], uni.array2[2]);

    /* print the size of the union */
    printf("size of union: %zu\n", sizeof(uni));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea whatsoever what a union actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(uni.array1)` is always 8 on 64-bit platforms and 4 on 32-bit ones because it is taking the size of a pointer, not knowing how much data you believe might be behind that pointer.  Similar for the arrays.  C pointers which you make point to an array are "dumb" and do not understand how large the array is--you need to pass that information around separately.

This covers your question parts 1 and 2.  We like to answer specific questions here, so feel free to move your third inquiry to a separate post.

Comment: Yeah, the problem here is that he thinks a pointer is an array, when it's not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Your union doesn't actually contain the arrays, it just contains (one of) two pointers. The size of a pointer on your machine is 8. If you want the arrays to be part of the union, do it this way

```
typedef union {
    char array1[MAX*8]; /* or whatever */
    double num;
    int array2[MAX];
} myunion;
```

The arrays have to have fixed length. That's the nature of compile-time types.